# ssh-keygen not generating public key

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen

As per the image shown below, when I run `ssh-keygen`, it says it created a public key. But when I browser by ssh folder, there's no public key.

[image]

Comment: You can always bake one with the private key: https://askubuntu.com/questions/53553/how-do-i-retrieve-the-public-key-from-a-ssh-private-key - also, could you try `sudo ls`, since thats something thats different from all other commands?

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you solved your problem. But for for the record, Stackoverflow is for help with software development. Questions like this are more at home on [unix.se] or [su]. Also, posting images of text is frowned on. In the future when you want to include program output in the question, you should include the output as text rather than an image.

Comment: @Kenster got it! Thanks for the correction!